# Working for US client as a UK company director in the US

Tags: b1-b2-visas, business-travel, work, conferences

**Context**

I am the director of a UK company.

My company has a contract to provide software engineering services to a US company.

I am also the worker providing those services.

I plan on taking a trip to the US to attend some tech conferences and engage in some tourist activites.

While there I intend to continue working remotely for the US client through my UK company.

**Questions**

- Should I apply for a B1/B2 visa?
- Are there any tax implications?
- Is it irrelevant given the contract is between the business entities?

Comment: Since you don't need a visa to attend conferences or as a tourist, your simplest option is certainly to not apply for a visa. It might be seen as a grey area: technically you need a visa to work in the US even if you're employed or contracted in the UK (excluding business meetings and some other exemptions), but nobody's going to worry about a small amount of work done during your trip. Length of stay is relevant, as is how much work you're going to be doing, and where you'll be doing it. If you fit work in around tourism, you can pretend you're not working.